# Fill a double array of different lengths for width and height of an image

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I'm making a program that needs to analyze an image completely every few pixels. This loop works with pictures that have the same height and width (they don't give me problems because they generate a perfect double array of colours). The problem occurs when the width and the height differ.

```
/** precondition
* img > 100x100px
* 
*/
private Color[][] matrizColours(File img) {
    int size = 10; //spacing between coordinate and coordinate
    int cord_x = size / 2, cord_y = size / 2; //coordinate
    BufferedImage image = null; 

    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(img);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    Color[][] a = new Color[image.getWidth() / size][image.getHeight() / size]; 
    int x = 0; //coordinate or array WIDTH
    int y = 0; //coordinate of array HEIGHT

    for (x = 0; cord_x <= image.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (y = 0; cord_y <= image.getHeight(); y++) {
            Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(cord_x, cord_y), true);
            a[x][y] = c;
            cord_y += size;
        }
        cord_x += size;
        cord_y = 5;
    }
    return a;
}
```

How can I fill the double array if the width and height differ? (what I want is a double array with different lengths)

I want the loop to keep going and continue filling the array when the width and height differ.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. "run an image completely"? "when the image is larger than another the parties"?

Comment: Sorry for me english, i go edit the question rigth now

Comment: what is gap? unclear plz add more details

Comment: Is the spacing between coordinate and coordinate, sorry the translator has malfunctioned

Comment: Do you want to have the same number of rows and columns in the array? even if image height and width are different?

Comment: No, what I want exactly is a double array with different lengths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand, why you need such a code...

But I really don't think your problem has anything to do with different width and height.

Imagine your Images has a width of 19 pixel. Your size is 10. If you divide 19/10, this makes 1,9. So your Color Array a has a length of 1.

Your cord_x starts with 5. After the first iteration, cord_x will be 15, which is still smaller than 19. So the for-loop will iterate twice, but your Array can only hold 1 x-Coordinate. So you will get an IndexOutOfBoundsException - Error.

Just improve the size of your Array, and no Exceptions should be thrown. (I suppose your width should be something like (int) (image.getWidth())/(1.0*size)+0.5) )

Comment: The measures are fixed I'm doing tests with images of more than 100px on each side, by far so good for the image of 100x100 but for example fails if one side is bigger, just do not know how to do the loop continue through the image although the conditions in the for be true.

In the final program size and the like be controlled before calling this method.

Comment: try: Color[][] a = new Color[ (int)((image.getWidth())/(1.0*size)+0.5)][ (int)((image.getHeight())/(1.0*size)+0.5)]; if your error isn't an java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - Error, please add more details. Because I can't reproduce any other error. This code works perfectely fine for me.

Comment: Now it works perfectly! Now we just need to fix other things the program! haha Thank you! : D